# How would you create a user interface for an iOS app for devices of all sizes?

Tags: ios

When creating an application is it possible to just get the dimensions of the device's screen and then to divide the dimensions by a number so that all UI elements will look similar on all devices?

I know that this can obviously be done, but is it something I should consider doing? Or should I consider creating multiple storyboard files to cover every single iOS device? Or is there a feature that storyboards have that allow you to do this and I just haven't discovered it yet?

If you set the sizes of UI elements to specific numbers (and not ratios) when you are programmatically adding the UI elements, the whole screen will look a bit off when you use a different device with a different screen size. So if I wanted to create user interfaces for all devices programmatically (without storyboards) would I have to write different code for each device? This is why I'm wondering if it would be better to just use ratios for the sizes. By doing that you will only have to write the code once.

Which way is best for designing for all screen sizes?

Comment: Use NSLayoutConstraints. You can set the size of views relative to the size of their superviews (as well as adjusting the position of those views based on screen size).

Comment: If you have access to WWDC 2014 videos, this topic is thoroughly addressed for iOS 8 ;).

Comment: When editing your storyboard, click on a component view, go to the left-most tab, and make sure the option use autoLayout is unchecked. Then go to the tab with the ruler on it (second from right) and modify the constraints below the frame details.

Answer (score 1):

> When creating an application is it possible to just get the dimensions
>   of the device's screen and then to divide the dimensions by a number
>   so that all UI elements will look similar on all devices?

No. It's proper only where it fits. Sometimes there's a situation which allows this scenario, but usually not. Because absolute size and proportion of devices are all different, and different layout needs different behaviors and interactions.

Think in users' perspective. Would you like to use such app? Well if you don't need UX quality, it's fine to do whatever.

There's no magic. Strictly saying, in worst case scenario, you need to always be prepared to write separated version of layout code for every each devices. If you have situations which can share a layout code (using whatever techniques), that's just lucky.

To optimize production, you can try to group devices in similar proportion. Apple calls this layout-idiom. Usually iOS devices builds two group --- phones and pads. In this case You need to make sure that all the UI components to support minimum range of flexibility in layout to deal with extra screen proportion fragmentation. Utilize

- Manual programmatic layout
- `NSLayoutConstraint`

for this.

In my experience, this is the most time-saving approach. Sometimes just making all version of layout is better, but this is rarely happen.